# How do I find the forum id in disqus

Tags: disqus

I am trying to follow this post [Retrieving all comments from Disqus with PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332080/retrieving-all-comments-from-disqus-with-php-script?rq=1)

My issue is: I don't know how to find my forum number, thread nunber, category number etc. Where can I find these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The forum ID is the `disqus_shortname` used in the [embed script](https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/).

I found this in the documentation:

http://disqus.com/api/docs/forums/details/

```
Looks up a forum by ID (aka short name)
```

Comment: But in the documentation, it says it looks up a forum by id. Where do you get the id from?

Comment: it also says "(aka short name)".

Comment: I'm sorry, I am very unfamiliar with disqus. I am working for a client who needs me do do work on it. Does that simply mean the forum name? Where do you create a forum name in disqus so I can test it. What about a thread id?

Comment: I tried a few numbers, and none worked. I just send a support question to disqus, we'll see if they answer.

Comment: dude, try the short name! If you look at the example of the page I linked, you'll see this: `"id":"bobross"`

Comment: @Xarcell is right, the forum id is the shortname. You can look on any page where comments are being loaded and find "var disqus_shortname", and this is the shortname to reference.

Comment: Thanks for the question. It was very constructive. Just wished people would answer more directly:  What is the form id? "it's the short name"  What's the short name? It's this: "id":"bobross" Where do you find that!? ... Ryan V if you only posted your answer sooner, it probably would have saved us all a bunch of time. ;)